# How to update a child component without re-rendering without Redux

Tags: reactjs

How do I update an adjacent (or child) component after a scroll event without re-rendering the parent component?

Adjacent scenario

```
<div>
  <Scrollable onScroll={ ... } />
  <DisplayPosition scrollEvent={ ... } />
</div>
```

Child scenario

```
return (
  <div onScroll={ ... }>
    <span> Don’t re-render me! </span>
    <DisplayPosition scrollEvent={ ... } />
  </div>
)
```

I am reluctant to reach for Redux for this problem as I would like to be able to solve it in a lightweight fashion

Answer (score 0):

## Without Redux

### ParentComponent

```
export default class ParentComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    let parentCallback = () => {};
    const onScroll = event => parentCallback(event);
    const didScroll = callback => parentCallback = callback;

    return (<div onScroll={onScroll}>
      <ChildrenComponent whenParent={didScroll} />
...
```

### ChildrenComponent

It will setup the callback to be executed by the parent

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.whenParent(event => this.setState({ event }));
}
```

By updating the state your ChildrenComponent will re-render. The ParentComponent will not re-render as nothing on its state or properties changed.

You'll have access to your event on `this.state.event`. Check the snippet for an example with click event.

```js
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log('hello ParentComponent');
    let parentCallback = () => {};
    const onClick = () => parentCallback(1);
    const didClick = callback => parentCallback = callback;

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={onClick}>Click To Add</button>
        <ChildrenComponent whenParent={didClick} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class ChildrenComponent extends React.Component {
  state = { sum: 0 };

  componentDidMount() {
    const { whenParent } = this.props;

    whenParent((adds) => {
      const { sum } = this.state;

      this.setState({ sum: sum + adds });
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log('hello ChildrenComponent');
   const { sum } = this.state;

    return <div>{sum}</div>;
  }
}
 
ReactDOM.render(
  <ParentComponent />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```